# Is there a way to throttle download/upload speeds through a router?

Tags: networking, router

I am wondering if there is anything I could do within my router (some D-link) to throttle the speed for different local IPs.

Comment: Depends on the router.  Probably not though.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the router's QoS feature to give your machine priority over the others.  Otherwise you can install a third party firmware to do traffic shaping.

**EDIT:**
Third Party firmware - [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php).  You can check if your model d-link is supported [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/dd-wrt/hardware.html).

Comment: I'll second the 3rd party firmware, I just wish it was working on my current router.

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to stuff up the installation of this and ruin my Dlink ? Is it possible to put the original firmware back on in case of emergency?

Answer (score 3):

If your router has some QoS features, then yes.  Look in the admin settings.

If not, you could use an old PC and [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org) or [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/)